# what should i use instead of 'Minus' Opertor in sql query for faster performance?

Tags: sql, plsql

I have a query like below, but this is responding slower day by day because register table data is increasing daily.i have also applied indexing on Register table but this is not enough.

```
(SELECT TRNDT,BATNO,TRNSL,TRNDES,TRNAMT,ORGBRCOD 
FROM table1
WHERE BRCOD=3555 AND ACTCOD=901 AND ACNO=44190 AND TRNAMT >=0 and 
orgbrcod<>3555 AND TRNDT> '13-JUL-2017'
)
MINUS
(SELECT T.TRNDT,T.BATNO,T.TRNSL,T.TRNDES,T.TRNAMT,T.ORGBRCOD 
FROM       
  (
     (SELECT TRNDT,BATNO,TRNSL,TRNDES,TRNAMT,ORGBRCOD 
      FROM table1
      WHERE BRCOD=3555 AND ACTCOD=901 AND ACNO=44190 AND TRNAMT >=0 and orgbrcod<>3555 AND TRNDT> '13-JUL-2017'
     )
  ) T,table2 REGISTER
    WHERE T.BATNO=REGISTER.BATNO_CR
    AND T.TRNSL=REGISTER.SL_CR
    AND T.TRNDT=REGISTER.TRNDT
  );
```

Comment: Use `exists` inplace of minus and see if you get some improvement. You would need to see the how `Exists` can be used before simply replacing it with Minus.

Comment: Step 1: look at the query plan and identify the highest cost. It may have nothing to do with the `minus` operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use minus. Use an outer join that *discards* matches:

```
SELECT a.TRNDT,a.BATNO,a.TRNSL,a.TRNDES,a.TRNAMT,a.ORGBRCOD 
FROM table1 a
WHERE a.BRCOD=3555 AND a.ACTCOD=901 AND a.ACNO=44190 AND a.TRNAMT >=0 and a.orgbrcod<>3555 AND a.TRNDT> '13-JUL-2017'
LEFT JOIN table2 REGISTER
    ON a.BATNO=REGISTER.BATNO_CR
    AND a.TRNSL=REGISTER.SL_CR
    AND a.TRNDT=REGISTER.TRNDT
WHERE REGISTER.BATNO_CR IS NULL
```

The trick here is that missed joins have all nulls in the joined table, and you want only those. By moving all the join conditions into the join clause allows an outer (ie `left`) join to be made so filtered can be done by requiring that the joined table have nulls.